# how to select two tables with limitations of 1?

Tags: php, mysql, select

**so, i am having a confusion right now and i do not have a enough knowledge to php. i have these two tables, the personal, and the senior. i need to depend on something: **

My personal table consist of: 
ExamineeID
FirstName
MiddleName
LastName
Age
ContactNumber

My senior table consist of :
SeniorID
LastSchoolAttended
Strand
SchoolAddress
Adviser
Honor1
Honor2
Honor3
Honor4
ExamineeID

I need the FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and LastSchoolAttended to be limit it to 1. Meaning, if FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and LastSchoolAttended has been exist, it will not be recorded. My Foreign key is the ExamineeID. I am trying to code but I know my code is so wrong.

```
$SELECTpersonal = "SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, LastSchoolAttended From personal, senior Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ? Limit 1";
        $SELECTsenior = "SELECT LastSchoolAttended, Strand, SchoolAddress, Adviser, Honor1, Honor2, Honor3, Honor4 From senior Where LastSchoolAttended = ?, Strand = ? And SchoolAddress = ? And Adviser = ? And Honor1 = ? And Honor2 = ? And Honor3 = ? And Honor4 = ? Limit 0";

        $INSERTpersonal = "INSERT Into personal (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, HomeAddress, ContactNumber, LastSchoolAttended) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $INSERTsenior = "INSERT Into senior (LastSchoolAttended, Strand, SchoolAddress, Adviser, Honor1, Honor2, Honor3, Honor4) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECTpersonal);
        $stmtsenior = $conn->prepare($SELECTsenior);
        $stmt -> bind_param("ssss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmtsenior -> bind_param("sssssss", $Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser,$Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmtsenior -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmtsenior -> bind_result($Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser,$Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmtsenior -> store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt -> num_rows;
        $rnumsenior = $stmtsenior -> num_rows;


        if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conn -> prepare($INSERTpersonal);

            $stmt -> bind_param("sssisis", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Age,$HomeAddress,$ContactNumber,$LastSchoolAttended);


            $stmt -> execute();

        }
        else if ($rnumsenior = 0 ){
            $stmtsenior->close();
            $stmt = $conn -> prepare($INSERTsenior);
            $stmt -> bind_param ("ssssssss",$LastSchoolAttended,$Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser,$Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
            $stmtsenior -> execute();


        }
```

For example, I inserted a data 
FirstName: Name1
MiddleName: MiddleName1
LastName: LastName1

and for the LastSchoolAttended, which came from the 2nd table:
LastSchoolAttended: School1.

if I inserted again, with the same data like the above, it will not be recorded because it is already exist and it is the basis if the examinees did their exam or not. I do not know how to connect each other.

Comment: "to be limit it to 1" is a bit vague. Edit your question to include some formatted sample data and expected results. You look like you want to insert the items if they don't exist. With a unique key this can be done without select statments with [insert ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: How can I do that without the select statement?

Comment: include sample data and expected results otherwise you'll just get a guess of an answer which may not be what you want.

Comment: I edited it now.

Comment: Store the senior honors in a separate table

Comment: so instead of separating the LastSchoolAttended to the first table, I just have to separate the Honor Table instead?